# login into Bitcoin

Tags: wallet

Good Night I have been receiving emails  about Bitcoin some stating that I have won Should I have received a login or a code.I don't remember signing up but I love new adventures ,and experiences. 
Thank you
Pamela

Comment: probably scam. and this is not really a question. so voted for closing

Answer (score 1):

> I have been receiving emails about Bitcoin some stating that I have won

It's a scam, just like the foreign prince who wants to share millions of dollars with you.  Ignore it.  Definitely don't send any money.  If you clicked on any of the links, scan your computer for viruses or other malware.

People acquire Bitcoins by paying for them, just like stocks or other investments.  Nobody is giving them away for free, certainly not to random people via email.

Comment: Seconded. If this question is actually legit, the rule of thumb is that if you get a random email from someone you don't know saying you've won something, just delete it.